# How Long Does it Take for Firefox to Automatically Update?

Tags: firefox

I recently updated to Firefox 30 by looking at the version number under `? -> About Firefox`, but I asked my coworker not to because I wanted to see how long it would take to do it on its own. So far, it hasn't updated after several reboots and openings of Firefox, even though he's configured for automatic updates. Will Firefox eventually try to update itself, or does the user have to manually trigger it like I did?

Comment: make sure the mozilla maintenance service is running if it ain't it wont update

Comment: Firefox updates are pushed the same day when they are released.  If a Firefox installation is not getting an updates it been configured that way.

Comment: @Ramhound The browser has the setting `Options -> Advanced -> Automatically install updates (recommended: improved security)` selected. Why isn't this sufficient?

Comment: @acbabis - There are other ways to stop Firefox from updating.

Comment: @acbabis I don't know why ramhound hasn't mentioned them - it's not very helpful of him, i'm not much of a ff user but if you ask him to tell you what he has in mind, and he answers you properly, then you might be able to check them and see if that is stopping it.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you elaborate? I think that would be the answer to the question.

Comment: There are Firefox group policy templates that might be the cause that's one of the ways I was thinking but I will let somebody else answer since I am not very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Well as I know you can find this in `about:config` just search for "update" and you will get this:
`app.update.interval`
This should be the "Interval" between updates which I think is in seconds.
Other than you can try to checl others like `app.update.silent` or maybe it is disabled so check `app.update.auto` and `app.update.enabled` and `app.update.silent`
All you could do is stored in `about:config`. Your last chance would be uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox (Be sure to backup data).

Comment: Yes `app.update.interval` is in seconds.  Default is (in FF v74) `43200` which is 12 hours.